# devise views in rails fetching from rvm gem set

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I was trying to install devise on my rails application.
So, when i was running my application ,the logs were showing that the rendered devise views are coming from /.rvm/gems/ruby 2.1.0/devise3.2.

i did the following

```
rails g devise:install 
rails g devise shop 
rails g devise:views shops
```

the logs:

```
Rendered /home/rawat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views/devise/shared/_links.slim (3.1ms)
Rendered /home/rawat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.slim within layouts/application (17.1ms)
Rendered static/_modal_user_account.html.slim (0.8ms)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you see the views in `app/views`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use what Devise calls **scoped views**.  Make sure you have the following:

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

[Devise README - Configuring Views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)